# How to change permission of database file in android?

Tags: android, database

From file explorer i am viewing my database file but not able to access the file can you tell me how to see the database columns and how to change the permissions of that file too.

Comment: would you talk about android ddms file explorer?

Comment: are you running your app in device?

Comment: pull that database file from the device.

Comment: what permission you want to change about database?

Comment: in the ddms file explorer i want to change the permissions from -rw-rw--- to -rwxrwxrwx

Answer (score 2):

```
1. open ddms -> file explorer -> file -> file -> <package name> -> database ->
   (select) databasename.db file -> pull file from the device (use pull button on 
  top-right of file explorer window) -> set the destination for file.

2. use any sqlite tools for open that database.db file and using it retrive or modify
   data of database.
```

Thnx.

EDIT: And for the permission, I didn't try it but I think, root your adb device (Emulator) and then change the permission of the appropriate file, For this you want to use adb tool and adb command.

EDIT: Look at [Understanding Android file permissions](http://androidforums.com/behold-2-all-things-root/73177-understanding-android-file-permissions.html) and [How to Use Android ADB Command Line Tool](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-use-android-adb-command-line-tool/)